# Do something with DOM7 after navigating to a different page

Tags: html-framework-7

I am trying to do something with [DOM7](https://framework7.io/docs/dom7.html) once a page has been opened from a specific other page. For example:

```
$$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="page-one"]', function (e) {
  $$('.page-content').find('#nextPage').on('click', function (e) { 
    app.views.main.router.navigate("/page-two/");
    $$('.hidden-content').removeClass('display-none');
  })
})
```

For my specific case, I cant show the hidden content when page-two is initialised. I only want the hidden content to be shown when page-two is opened from a specific other page.